# Stock High Charts with Custom points on X-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a requirement where i have to show custom points on x-axis instead of dates values. Also same custom data points needs to be shown on navigator as well. In the below Js fiddle, i am converting data (Per13/2016 etc) into equivalent date values and then binding the chart using converted date values.
 Below is the link of the JS fiddle:- [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qneuh4Ld/)

In the Js fiddle, i am showing Per1,Per2 etc.on x-axis and same has to be  shown on navigator as well.
    Now i am facing problem with the navigator,when i changes the range using slider ,the x-axis labels changes but not according to the range selected.Also tool-tip formatting is getting changed.

Can you please let me know how to handle this scenario and best way to do the same.

```
        //few code lines to post fiddle link   
          xAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            if(fiscal13){
                            var perDate = new Date(this.value);
                            return 'Per' + (perDate.getMonth() + 1);
                            }

              }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Add this > var s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%e  %b  %Y',
                                          new Date(this.x));  for tooltip , I'll update solution for nagitor as well http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/qneuh4Ld/1/

Comment: I need to show Per 1, Per 2 etc along with cost and usage on tool-tip but the problem is when the slider moves tool-tip text changes and data on the chart also not shown as per the range selection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am right, but I think you are overdoing this.

Let's keep original data, so remove `fiscal13Data.Data.forEach(function(item) { .. });` function. And When creating data, use simply index of the point as x-value:

```
var cost = [],
  usage = [],
  dataLength = fiscal13Data.Data.length
i = 0;
for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
  // need to sum costs
  cost.push([
    i, // the index
    fiscal13Data.Data[i]['Cost'] // cost
  ]);
  usage.push([
    i, // the index
    fiscal13Data.Data[i]['Usage'] // Usage
  ]);
}
```

Now you can get to the "Per13/2016" strings in a simple way in xAxis labels' formatters:

```
var str = fiscal13Data.Data[this.value].Date;
```

In tooltip formatter, it is almost exactly the same:

```
var str = fiscal13Data.Data[this.x].Date;
```

And here is working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qneuh4Ld/3/

Note: You data looks a bit strange - don't you want to sort it first? Also, you have twice every date (e.g. "Per13/2016" - once for "water" and once for "electric").